# How to redirect short link url to particular page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect https://www.test.com/?p=6745 this type of URL to home page. Right now it gives 404 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=6745
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: With this code I am getting to many redirects

Comment: Is there anyone to reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=6745
RewriteRule ^ / [QSD,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

With **QSD** flag:

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI
>   does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query
>   string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string
>   to be discarded.
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

This flag is available in Apache version 2.4.0 and later. Before, use:

```
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```